# Const receiving a var, i cant pass it to a template

Tags: c++

What I want to do is:

```
int const bitsPerInt = log2(X);
bitset<bitsPerInt>  bits(a random number...);
```

but I get this error:

> 'bitsPerInt' cannot appear in a constant expression
>   error: template argument 1 is invalid

Comment: use `std::vector<bool>`

Comment: log2(X) can be known at compile time? maybe duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341396/c-cannot-appear-in-a-constant-expression-i-need-this-to-be-a-variable-why

Comment: The error is very clear... `bitsPerInt` is a const, but not a constant expression aka `constexpr`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really need this to work, make your own `log2` that works in compile-time and pass it to bitset's template argument.

```
constexpr unsigned Log2(unsigned n, unsigned p = 0) {
    return (n <= 1) ? p : Log2(n / 2, p + 1);
}

constexpr size_t bitCount = Log2(X);
std::bitset<bitCount> bits;
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c7039bb1ece748b3).

---

Here's the solution using template meta-programming i.e. without using `constexpr`:

```
template<int N,unsigned int P=0>
struct Log2 { enum { value = Log2<N/2,P+1>::value }; };

template <unsigned p>
struct Log2<0, p> { enum { value = p }; };

template <unsigned p>
struct Log2<1, p> { enum { value = p }; };

std::bitset<Log2<4>::value> bits;
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c93fb4a76e6d21d).

This version should work in both C++03 and C++11; however, if you've access to C++11, I'd still recommend the `constexpr` way since it's cleaner (easier to understand).

Comment: I guess there is also a way with template meta programming but I am not quite there yet. Nonetheless, nice solution.

Comment: Yes, if you don't've access to C++11, then the same can be done with metaprogramming too.

Comment: Theres a way to do this without the need of use constexpr? Because it is c++11, and besides that, I am not familiar with constexpr yet... Thanks for your help!

Comment: @EricFortin: There! Added the meta-programming version since the OP asked for it :)

Comment: @ViperAlpha: I've added that case too, but it requires you to understand a little bit of meta-programming. Both will work only at compile-time; if you really have variable values for `X`, then `bitset` isn't for you, you should use `vector<bool>`.

Comment: @legends2k, thanks so much for the help, but the error still goes on, now it says that : "The value of 'X' is not usable in a constant expression bitset<Log2<X>::value> bits;

Comment: @ViperAlpha: I think you don't understand the nature of templates in C++ E.g. `std::bitset<4>` and `std::bitset<8>` are 2 completely different types and at run-time will have different characterstics. At compile-time, based on the template argument passed, the compiler will generate two independant types, thus the arguments passed should also be compile-time constants. You should really consider using `vector<bool>` or `boost::dynamic_bitset` which can grow to any length at run-time.

Comment: I understand this part you said , but theres no way I use a template within a value choosen by user?

Comment: You mean the user entering something as input? Then that value is yet-to-be-known or in other words, it's not a compile-time known constant value and it can change, hence you've to use a container that can grow it's size at run-time; while bitset's size will be fixed at compile-time; at run-time no changes can be made to it. They're like arrays.

Comment: Yes, the user would input some number (power of 2)

Comment: Since I can't voteup, I will just mark your question as the correct one, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Template parameter needs to be known(and constant if it is a value and not a type) at compile time. This is how templates work in C++. Templates actually generate real code for each specific version of the generic code.

Comment: Yes I know, but the problem is, its variable, theres no way to do it?

Comment: With templates and a runtime value, no.